# Visual Studio 2012 running Windows Phone issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compiler-errors, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone project that I write in Visual Studio 2012 and I have a problem that every time:

1. Run a project on my device
2. Stop it
3. I edit some code
4. Save the project
5. Try to run my app again on my device and get this message:

   > Could not copy "obj\Debug\xxxx.dll" to "Bin\Debug\xxxx.dll". 
   >   Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.*

Comment: You should check that the "Bin\Debug\xxxx.dll" file isn't read-only.

Comment: as KooKiz points out, such dll file is being used for other process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known bug. Just restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than restarting Visual studio try terminating XDesProc.exe
The designer has reference to the dll it seems